# Iterating over files in PLSQL

Tags: plsql, oracle10g

Using a PLSQL script, is it possible to iterate over binary files in a folder and insert them as a BLOB in Oracle 10g? Any examples would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using PL/SQL how do you I get a file's contents in to a blob?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122909/using-pl-sql-how-do-you-i-get-a-files-contents-in-to-a-blob)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting a file's contents to a blob is covered here: [Using PL/SQL how do you I get a file's contents in to a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122909/using-pl-sql-how-do-you-i-get-a-files-contents-in-to-a-blob)

However this doesn't help you iterate over multiple files in a directory.

Two possible solutions for this:

#### Solution 1: `SYS.DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE.searchFiles`

You can pass this procedure your search criteria and it populates a global in-memory table with the list of results over which you can then iterate like so:

```
DECLARE

pattern VARCHAR2(1024) := '/u01/oracle/admin/SID/udump';
ns VARCHAR2(1024);

BEGIN
SYS.DBMS_BACKUP_RESTORE.searchFiles(pattern, ns);

FOR each_file IN (SELECT FNAME_KRBMSFT AS name FROM X$KRBMSFT WHERE FNAME_KRBMSFT LIKE '%.trc') LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(each_file.name);
END LOOP;

END;
/
```

See a full example complete with an excellent explanation [here](http://www.chrispoole.co.uk/tips/plsqltip2.htm).

#### Solution 2: Java

The great Tom "AskTom" Kyte shows how to iterate over files using a Java procedure [here](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0:::%20:P11_QUESTION_ID:439619916584).