# oracle sql error: Inserting a picture in blob format

Tags: sql, oracle, image, insert, blob

I try to insert a picture to the next table:

```
create   table Picture 
(
    pic BLOB,
    title varchar2(30),
    descript varchar2(200),
    tags varchar2(100),
    date_created varchar2(100),
    actualdate date
);
```

I have a picture and 5 varchar2 paramaters. Here is the procedure where I want to insert:

```
create or replace procedure addKep (pic BLOB, title varchar2,descript varchar2, tags varchar2 , date_created varchar2, hiba out varchar2)
is

my_date date;
v_blob BLOB;

begin 
    --get actual date
    SELECT TO_date 
    (SYSDATE, 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:MI:SS')into my_date
    FROM DUAL;    

    INSERT INTO Picture (pic)
    VALUES (empty_blob());

    insert into Picture Values(pic,title,descript,tags,date_created,my_date);
    --hiba:='Sikeres!';

    commit;
end;
```

After I try to test my procedure:

```
declare 
something varchar2(20);
BEGIN 
addKep('c:\xampp\htdocs\php_web\_projekt\pic\akosfeladatok.jpg','Title','Description','tags','2020-06-15',something); 
END;
```

But I will get the next error:

```
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'ADDKEP'
```

However, I have the same argument list

Thank you for your help

Comment: You don't pass a path to a file as a BLOB, you pass the actual bytes of the file - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122909/using-pl-sql-how-do-you-i-get-a-files-contents-in-to-a-blob - note `c:\xampp\htdocs\php_web\_projekt\pic` should be a path on the server, not your localmachine (unless your local machine is the server..)

Comment: Your argument "pic" contains the path to the file, not the file. You can't load a file like that. Does this help ?  https://blogs.oracle.com/searchtech/loading-documents-and-other-file-data-into-the-oracle-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't pass a path to a file as a BLOB, you pass the actual bytes of the file - see [Using PL/SQL how do you I get a file's contents in to a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122909/using-pl-sql-how-do-you-i-get-a-files-contents-in-to-a-blob)

Though, I (personally) dare say your problematic code has the right idea; I'd recommend to NOT store your pictures inside your database. Store them in the file system as files and then use the paths in the DB. It's handy for all sorts of things such as being able to individually back them up, manipulate or substitute them, and you don't need to write code in order to serve them over the web; web servers already know how to serve files out of the file system but as soon as you put your picture (or any bytes data) into a DB, it becomes much harder to work with and you have to write all the code that pulls it out, and puts it back - and that's really all you can do. By storing files in your mission critical DB it means the DB now has to dedicate resources to fetching those files out any time they're needed - really files like pictures should be put on a CDN and made available close to the users who will use them/the job of storing, caching and serving them be handed off to existing technologies dedicated to the task

ps; There are a lot of reasonable arguments for and against, in https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/2445/should-binary-files-be-stored-in-the-database - my thoughts, personally, align with Tek's